# How to create QTextList Decimal starting from a particular number

Tags: list, qt, formatting, richtext, qtextedit

I know how to create a list in a QTextEdit (see the code below, which is the most important part). I was wondering if I could create a numbered list, **starting from a particular number**.

For example, each time a list is made:

1. It
2. Starts from the number
3. One.

But I was wondering if qt supports lists that

5. Start from
6. Any number specified.

In the docs, there's QTextListFormat::setNumberPrefix but it seems to me that that's what appears before the numbers. Thanks.

Central Function:

```
void CreateQuestionForm::list(bool checked, QTextListFormat::Style style) {
QTextCursor cursor = ui->f_textedit->textCursor();
cursor.beginEditBlock();
if (!checked) {
    QTextBlockFormat obfmt = cursor.blockFormat();
    QTextBlockFormat bfmt;
    bfmt.setIndent(obfmt.indent());
    cursor.setBlockFormat(bfmt);
  } else {
    QTextListFormat listFmt;
    if (cursor.currentList()) {
        listFmt = cursor.currentList()->format();
        }
    listFmt.setStyle(style);
    cursor.createList(listFmt);
    }
cursor.endEditBlock();
}
```

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: @eyllanesc That is the central list-making function

Comment: You could explain what you want to get because I do not understand you. Maybe show the exit you want to get help to understand you.

Comment: @eyllanesc for example, there could be a .startsfrom attribute of the QTextListFormat object, to specify what integer it starts from

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Qt 6.6, the Qt has implemented the mentioned method `void QTextListFormat::setStart(int start)` with corresponding query method `int QTextListFormat::start` (evidence: https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/dev/src/gui/text/qtextformat.cpp#L2759)

However, when you want to use this method before Qt 6.6, I suggest you subclass the `QTextList`, `QTextListFormat`, and handle the `QTextCursor::insertList` with proper methods such as setting `objectIndex`es, overriding `QTextBlockFormat` settings, ... But after the Qt 6.6 release in about half a year later, things are getting simple if your computer allows the compatibility of the newest Qt.

Edit:

Now, Qt is still 6.4. Qt 6.5 is coming out by beta in Apr 9 2023. According to the average releasing speed of the past versions of Qt, I can determine that Qt 6.6 will release its source code and online installer half year later.

MRE after 6.6:

```cpp
// ......
void QmyTextEdit::insertList()
{
    QTextListFormat form;
    QTextListFormat = QTextListFormat();
    QTextListFormat.setStart(3);
    QTextListFormat.setStyle(QTextListFormat::ListDecimal);
    // m_cursor = textCursor();
    m_cursor.createList(form);
}
// ....
```

However, before Qt 6.6, ***WITHOUT TESTING. THERE MAY BE SOME BUGS.***,

##### QmyTextList.h

```cpp
// ...
class QmyTextList : public QTextList
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    QmyTextList(QTextDocument &doc);
    void setStart(int start);
    int start();
    QString itemText(const QTextBlock &blockIt) const;
private:
    int m_start;
};
// ...
```

##### QmyTextList.cpp

```cpp
// ...
    : QTextList(doc)
{
    setStart(1)
}

void QmyTextList::setStart(int start)
{
    if (start != m_start)
        m_start = start;
}

int QmyTextList::start()
{
    return m_start;
}

QString QmyTextList::itemText(const QTextBlock &blockIt) const
{
    Q_D(const QTextList);
    int item = blockIt.blockNumber();
    if (item <= 0)
        return QString();

    QTextBlock block = blockIt.previousBlock();
    QTextBlockFormat blockFormat = block.blockFormat();

    QString result;

    const int style = format().style();
    QString numberPrefix;
    QString numberSuffix = u"."_s;

    // the number of the item might be offset by start, which defaults to 1
    const int itemNumber = (item + format().start() - 1) + m_start;

    if (format().hasProperty(QTextFormat::ListNumberPrefix))
        numberPrefix = format().numberPrefix();
    if (format().hasProperty(QTextFormat::ListNumberSuffix))
        numberSuffix = format().numberSuffix();

    switch (style) {
        case QTextListFormat::ListDecimal:
            result = QString::number(itemNumber);
            break;
            // from the old richtext
        case QTextListFormat::ListLowerAlpha:
        case QTextListFormat::ListUpperAlpha:
            {
                // match the html default behavior of falling back to decimal numbers
                if (itemNumber < 1) {
                    result = QString::number(itemNumber);
                    break;
                }

                const char baseChar = style == QTextListFormat::ListUpperAlpha ? 'A' : 'a';

                int c = itemNumber;
                while (c > 0) {
                    c--;
                    result.prepend(QChar::fromUcs2(baseChar + (c % 26)));
                    c /= 26;
                }
            }
            break;
        case QTextListFormat::ListLowerRoman:
        case QTextListFormat::ListUpperRoman:
            {
                // match the html default behavior of falling back to decimal numbers
                if (itemNumber < 1) {
                    result = QString::number(itemNumber);
                } else if (itemNumber < 5000) {
                    QByteArray romanNumeral;

                    // works for up to 4999 items
                    static const char romanSymbolsLower[] = "iiivixxxlxcccdcmmmm";
                    static const char romanSymbolsUpper[] = "IIIVIXXXLXCCCDCMMMM";
                    QByteArray romanSymbols; // wrap to have "mid"
                    if (style == QTextListFormat::ListLowerRoman)
                        romanSymbols = QByteArray::fromRawData(romanSymbolsLower, sizeof(romanSymbolsLower));
                    else
                        romanSymbols = QByteArray::fromRawData(romanSymbolsUpper, sizeof(romanSymbolsUpper));

                    int c[] = { 1, 4, 5, 9, 10, 40, 50, 90, 100, 400, 500, 900, 1000 };
                    int n = itemNumber;
                    for (int i = 12; i >= 0; n %= c[i], i--) {
                        int q = n / c[i];
                        if (q > 0) {
                            int startDigit = i + (i+3)/4;
                            int numDigits;
                            if (i % 4) {
                                // c[i] == 4|5|9|40|50|90|400|500|900
                                if ((i-2) % 4) {
                                    // c[i] == 4|9|40|90|400|900 => with subtraction (IV, IX, XL, XC, ...)
                                    numDigits = 2;
                                }
                                else {
                                    // c[i] == 5|50|500 (V, L, D)
                                    numDigits = 1;
                                }
                            }
                            else {
                                // c[i] == 1|10|100|1000 (I, II, III, X, XX, ...)
                                numDigits = q;
                            }

                            romanNumeral.append(romanSymbols.mid(startDigit, numDigits));
                        }
                    }
                    result = QString::fromLatin1(romanNumeral);
                } else {
                    result = u"?"_s;
                }

            }
            break;
        default:
            Q_ASSERT(false);
    }
    if (blockIt.textDirection() == Qt::RightToLeft)
        return numberSuffix + result + numberPrefix;
    else
        return numberPrefix + result + numberSuffix;
}
```

When insert a list,

```cpp
QTextCursor cur_ = textCursor();
QTextListFormat format_ = QTextListFormat()
format_.setStyle(QTextListForamt::ListDisc);
QmyTextList* list = static_cast<QmyTextList *>document()->createObject(format_);
QTextBlockFormat modifier;
modifier = QTextBlockFormat();
modifier.setObjectIndex(list->objectIndex());
cur_.mergeBlockFormat(modifier);
```

## WARNING : The above code is not a complete Minimal-Reproductive-Example (sorry)

## WARNING : The code above is not tested, or even implemented at all. Read the following suggestions.

My suggestion is, however, wait until the release of Qt 6.6, and *use* the `setStart` method.